# $\frac {(x-y)}{x}$ Can it be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I appreciate anyone taking a look at this.

It's been ages since I've been in algebra/calculus and need to figure out if $\dfrac {(x-y)}{x}$ can be simplified or would it be $\left(1 - \dfrac yx\right)$?

Thank you,

Josh

Thanks to all the very speedy responses.  I guess my algebra isn't as rusty as I thought.  This question can be marked as solved/closed.

Comment: you already write its possibility to solve by $1-\frac yx$.Can you do more clear your ques?

Comment: @iostream007 I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I'll remember it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1-\frac yx$ is the best you will do for most purposes. Sometimes the original will be better, depending on the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to remember: it's always easy to add or subtract fractions with the same denominator. (If you cut a pie into eighths, and you select seven eighths of it, and take away four eigths, you're still left with three eighths.)

So 
$$
\frac{x - y}{z} = \frac{x}{z} - \frac{y}{z}
$$

In your case $x = z$ and the first fraction simplifies to $1$ (eight eighths of a pie minus three eighths of a pie is five eighths of a pie).

If you try to do the same reasoning with denominators of a fraction, you'll get junk (four eighths of a pie minus four sevenths of a pie $\neq$ four negative oneths of a pie). So don't try to simplify something like
$$
\frac{x}{x - y}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it to $\left(1-\dfrac yx\right)$ as you said .